# slide right to left div on hover jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good day,
I'm having trouble with jquery. i found a topic here that i want to learn using jquery slide right to left div http://jsfiddle.net/PXLJG/2/.

what i want to achieve is when hover, show hidden content on specific div.
i tried adding `.addClass('active');` to the script.
here is the script i made

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.holdingbox').hover(function(){
        var rightbox = $('.rightbox');
        if (rightbox.hasClass('active')){
            rightbox.stop().animate({width: '-0px'}, 1000).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            rightbox.stop().animate({width: '90px'}, 1000).addClass('active');
        }
        });
    });
```

The problem now is when i hover on one div, all div shows up.[Please see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEwV7.png).
Hope you guys can point me to right direction. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target the *rightbox* element in current element context i.e. `this`

You can either use [context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) or [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target child element.

```
$('.holdingbox').hover(function() {
   var rightbox = $('.rightbox', this); //$(this).find('.rightbox')
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.holdingbox').hover(function() {
     var rightbox = $('.rightbox', this);
     if (rightbox.hasClass('active')) {
       rightbox.stop().animate({
         width: '-0px'
       }, 1000).removeClass('active');
     } else {
       rightbox.stop().animate({
         width: '90px'
       }, 1000).addClass('active');
     }
   });
 });
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.holdingbox {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.leftbox {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #ac193d;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1px;
}

.rightbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.content {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ac193d;
  height: 29px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holdingbox">
  <span class="rightbox"><span class="content">Kenyér</span></span>
  <span class="leftbox">></span>
 </div>

<div class="holdingbox">
  <span class="rightbox">
  <span class="content">Kenyér</span>
  </span>
  <span class="leftbox">></span>
</div>
```

Comment: its working now. can you explain to me why adding this worked? thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Gilberte., Using context or `.find()`, its only targeting the child _rightbox _ element of _holdingbox_

Answer (score 0):

Change code to this

You'll get children of the hovered element this way. Without using $(this) you target all '.rightbox' elements in document.

```
   $('.holdingbox').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.rightbox').stop().animate({width: '90px'}, 1000)
}, function(){
    $(this).find('.rightbox').stop().animate({width: '-0'}, 1000)
});
```